# Loop through a set of dynamic fields

Tags: custom-field

I have a field set on a object and name of the field set is same as the recordtype of record. I am looping through a list of records and according to the name of recordtype need to display all the fields from field set. The fields need to be displayed dynamically. I have a map which contain fieldset name and related fields. I am getting all the fields from the map and looping through and trying to display it from a List from map. How can it be possible please guide me.

```
public Map<String, List<String>>  fieldSetField = new Map<String, List<String>>();   
for(String fieldName : fieldSetField.get(((ConfiguredItemWrapper.get(num)[0].configuredItem.Recordtype.Name.trim()).replace(' ', '_')).toLowerCase())){
               gen.writeStringField(fieldName, ConfiguredItemWrapper.get(num)[0].configuredItem.Name);
}
```

in `ConfiguredItemWrapper.get(num)[0].configuredItem.`here I want to put the dynamic field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SObject.get(fieldName)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) method to get the value of a field by passing the field name from your list of field names..

```
for(String fieldName : fieldSetField.get(((ConfiguredItemWrapper.get(num)[0].configuredItem.Recordtype.Name.trim()).replace(' ', '_')).toLowerCase())){
               gen.writeStringField(fieldName, ConfiguredItemWrapper.get(num)[0].configuredItem.get(fieldName));
}
```