# how to fetch field values from list based on variable values

Tags: soql

I have an account list which is returned from a dynamic query based on field api names stored in custom metadata, We are trying to pass this information(the field name and its corresponding value) returned from query to a wrapper class. But the challenge i am facing is i am unable to fetch the field values based on variable input, Please see below.

```
    List<Account> accountList = Database.query(query);
            List<String> lstOfFields = sfFields.Fields_API_Name__c.split(',');
    for(String fieldname : lstOfFields){
        wrapper.add(fieldname,accountList[0].fieldname,category);    
    }
```

sfFields is the custom metadata which stores the api names of the fields as comma seperated values. When i try to access the field value from accountList using the below syntax accountList[0].fieldname , it gives us an error variable does not exist fieldname.

Can some one please assist how can we achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the SObject class methods. You can use `get` to access field values by string name or describe, for example. Here the type of the field's value is exposed as the Object base class.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through a set of dynamic fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92089/loop-through-a-set-of-dynamic-fields)

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below. Note that `Sobject` has `get` and `put` which accepts field name as dynamic input and gets/sets the given value.

```
    List<Account> accountList = Database.query(query);
    List<String> lstOfFields = sfFields.Fields_API_Name__c.split(',');
    
    for(String fieldname : lstOfFields){
        wrapper.add(fieldname,accountList[0].get(fieldname),category);    
    }
```